# How to swap the column header in pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, levels

Following up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167931/how-to-pivot-table-by-parentauction-column-in-such-a-way-that-i-get-output-shown/46168123#46168123)

I got a datframe after pivoting like this .

```
                      AVG GrossProfit      AVG PMV      Loss%         Sales      
ParentAuction       Copart   IAA        Copart   IAA   Copart IAA    Copart   IAA 
Make                                                                        
Acura               112.99  NaN         -15.53   NaN   36.46  NaN      96.0  NaN
```

How to change the column levels to this format of columns ?

```
ParentAuction                 Copart                                    IAA          
                 AVG GrossProfit AVG PMV  Loss%  Sales  AVG GrossProfit AVG PMV   Loss%   Sales  
Make                                                                          
Acura                  112.99  -15.53  36.46   96.0             NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
ParentAuction           Copart                                  IAA          \
               AVG GrossProfit AVG PMV  Loss% Sales AVG GrossProfit AVG PMV   
Make                                                                          
Acura                   112.99  -15.53  36.46  96.0             NaN     NaN   

ParentAuction               
               Loss% Sales  
Make                        
Acura            NaN   NaN
```